# How to set a Vim autocmd for any file in &packpath?

Tags: vim

I need to set an autocommand that will execute after writing any file in vim's `&packpath` (and in its subdirectories).
How would I go about doing this, given that `&packpath` is a list of many directories? I don't know much vimscript, so please excuse me if this a simple question.

I have tried:

```
autocmd BufWritePost &packpath/* [command here]
```

but this does not work.

How would one do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two parts to your problem.

The first part is about consuming an expression in an Ex command and the second part is about constructing the proper autocommand pattern.

In Vim, an expression is anything that must be evaluated to produce a value. In this case, `&packpath` is an expression whose evaluation produces a string in the form:

```
dirA,dirB,dirC
```

Most Ex commands expect strings, not expressions, though, and the classic solution to this "problem" is to use `:help :execute`:

```
execute 'autocmd BufWritePost ' .. &packpath .. ' echomsg "Hello."'
```

which concatenates those strings and evaluated expressions into a proper autocommand:

```
autocmd BufWritePost dirA,dirB,dirC echomsg "Hello."
```

that… does nothing because we still have the second part to deal with.

As `:help file-pattern` shows, autocommand "patterns" are a lot like the globbing patterns you are used to in your shell, with a little sprinkling of regular expressions. Just like in your shell, the proper "pattern" for "any Vim file directly under any directory in `&runtimepath`" would be:

```
{dirA,dirB,dirC}/*.vim
```

and the one for "any Vim file under any directory in `&runtimepath`, recursively" would be:

```
{dirA,dirB,dirC}/**/*.vim
```

Let's adapt our command:

```
execute 'autocmd BufWritePost {' .. &packpath .. '}/**/*.vim echomsg "Hello."'
```

which, indeed, annoyingly prints `Hello.` every time we write a file somewhere in `&runtimepath`.